# Do I need "though" in the following sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

> The forest seemed endless. Either that or we
>   were going in circles; it seemed like the same trees kept passing by,
>   like the looped backgrounds in old cowboy chasing scenes. Just as I
>   was about to lose hope, **though**, the trees cleared away, and Tom and
>   I found ourselves in a small valley.

Two people told me that I don't need the *though.* But, I don't know, I feel it's necessary to add one, because the sentence is saying: "We were going in circles and I was about to give up, **but** I finally didn't because we found our way out."

Or maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it sounds natural with "though".  Placed where it is, *though*  imparts a conversational quality to the story.  If it were placed at the beginning of the sentence, the effect would be less conversational:

Though just as I was about to lose hope, the trees cleared away...

P.S. We call them "*chase* scenes".

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mean I should remove the cowboy part?

Comment: what is the chase sense ? As I know, we use "though" and "although" in adverbial clauses. what do you mean effect is less conversational ? Are you refer to informal speech ? And , the final question, P.S stands for what ? :)

Comment: @Cardinal: P.S. = postscript.  The OP wrote: "...like the looped backgrounds in old cowboy chasing[sic] scenes".

Comment: @alexchenco: You can keep the cowboy part. It was good.  I just meant that we don't call them "chasing" scenes but "chase scenes".

Answer (score 1):

If you were telling this story in casual spoken English, you could certainly use "though" here the way you have it. However, in writing I would recommend you use **however** or **but** at the beginning of the sentence:

> However, just as I was about to lose hope, the trees cleared away...

If it were me telling or writing the story, I would personally use **then** followed by a pause:

> Then, just as I was about to lose hope, ...

Comment: So you also think that the sentence would sound weird without the "though"?

Comment: It would sound fine with "though," but it would read better without it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above. There seems enough change in the action that "though" is a good support in the narrative (else I would just remove it).

Also, I would add a comma after "Either that" .